# Header PHP Icon Link

Tags: php, html

Why is this not linking i have added it to my header PHP file?

```
<a href="https://keepmovingcare.com/cart/">
<img class="basketicon" id="topL" src="<?php echo get_stylesheet_directory_uri(); ?>/images/bag.png"/></a>
<?php endif; ?>
<a href="https://keepmovingcare.com/cart/"><span class="basket-number">
<?php
global $woocommerce;
echo $woocommerce->cart->cart_contents_count;
?>
</span></a>
```

It used to look like this:

```
<?php endif; ?>

<?php
if ( ! $et_top_info_defined && ( ! $et_slide_header || is_customize_preview() ) ) {
et_show_cart_total( array(
'no_text' => true,
) );
}
?>
```

Though I followed some guides to show the cart in the main nav as opposed to the secondary nav though it doesn't link, removing the php end if breaks the site, though would that affect the linking?

It renders this icon:

[bag icon](https://i.stack.imgur.com/waWTc.png)

I can see the links in inspect but they aren't clickable:

[inspection code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sIKzB.png)

Comment: Where is the start point of your if statement?

Comment: Can you show what it renders in your browser?

Comment: @MichaelRennison have added it

Comment: @Tushar have added the previous code if that helps

Comment: What can you see in the src tag if you inspect element in your browser?

Comment: @MichaelRennison i can actually see the links weirdly, though not clickable